# ERROR in ./src/img - Webpack

Tags: webpack

so I ran into an issue with the webpack-image-loader where it will no longer load images correctly. I am not exactly sure what is wrong with it, but it throws these errors...

```
ERROR in ./src/img/logo.png
    Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
        at isBinary (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/is-svg/index.js:8:38)
        at module.exports (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/is-svg/index.js:19:10)
        at /Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/imagemin-svgo/index.js:8:7
        at Imagemin.use (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/node_modules/imagemin/index.js:63:51)
        at Object.module.exports (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js:33:6)
     @ ./src/components/containers/routes/Signup.js 35:42-74
```

It appears to be an issue with `is-svg`. Not sure exactly what I'm supposed to do about this issue. I modified the node_module to return false... And it seems to have a streaming issue:

```
ERROR in ./src/img/logo.png
Module build failed: TypeError: stream.on is not a function
    at Readable.wrap (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:740:10)
    at wrap (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/stream-combiner2/index.js:67:29)
    at combine (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/stream-combiner2/index.js:29:18)
    at Function.module.exports.obj (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/stream-combiner2/index.js:22:10)
    at Imagemin.createStream (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/node_modules/imagemin/index.js:103:24)
    at Imagemin.run (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/node_modules/imagemin/index.js:77:20)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/chriscates/projects/web-frontend-assets/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js:43:14)
 @ ./src/components/containers/routes/Index.js 29:42-74
```

Any clues on how to debug this?

Comment: related to this? https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/167

Comment: I followed the advice in that github issue and it didn't resolve it... Hmmm